Reading xlsx file into lambda function AWS
Trying to read an xlsx file from an S3 bucket. Lambda function is called but I get the following 'seek' error
[ERROR] UnsupportedOperation: seek
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    df = pd.read_excel(xl_file\['Body'\], dtype_backend='pyarrow', header=\[1,2\])
File "/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/\_base.py", line 495, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(
File "/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/\_base.py", line 1550, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
File "/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/\_base.py", line 1406, in inspect_excel_format
    stream.seek(0)

...and here is my lambda function (the part that is relevant). Header is spread across rows 1 and 2.  Code runs fine in it's local form (i.e. when pulling xlsx file from a local directory)
import json
import boto3
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd

s3Client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    xl_file = s3Client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
    df = pd.read_excel(xl_file['Body'], dtype_backend='pyarrow', header=[1,2])


Fixed with
xl_file_body = io.BytesIO(xl_file['Body'].read())
Also had to increase timeout limit in S3. Was timing out with default 3 seconds (900 rows and 10 columns in a sample file), so increased to 30 seconds and completed in 14 seconds

FYI that timeout limit is not in S3. It's the Lambda function timeout.

Working code as follows
import boto3
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

s3Client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    xl_file = s3Client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
    xl_file_body = io.BytesIO(xl_file['Body'].read()) 
    df = pd.read_excel(xl_file_body, dtype_backend='pyarrow', header=[1,2])

